# What is the difference between active record callback and association callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I know how the callback working and when they are get call, like **Active record callbacks hook into the life cycle of Active Record objects, allowing you to work with those objects at various points.**

But i am not clear about how the association callback call, I found in ruby on rails guide describe that **Association callback triggered by events in the life cycle of a collection.** In that point i am not clear about when they are get call.

I would appreciate if anyone make me clear by giving some example here.

Comment: Why not [this example](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks) is clear to you ? This is a callback which will occur when you are adding records to the child table via the parent table..

Comment: Ok.. then ?? What is confusing there.. ? :)

Comment: If i have User has_many Friends, then it'll call when i wrote user.friends.build ? You can assume i have association call back within friends relationship.

Comment: If you defined them, then you have.. It wouldn't come _free_ :D

Comment: We defined them in that way so that they can able to come free :D :P

Comment: Ok.. then you have.. You will see the _effect_ of it, when you will call `#save`. Because `#build` is in memory objects.. When you will try to get them saves to the DB, then the real _kick_ will come.. :) try in _console_